# Javascript toggle or if/else on Adobe Edge Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, if, else, jquery-animate

Eu uso o Adobe Edge Animate para animações simples no trabalho. Não consegui fazer uma delas funcionar e fiz uma gambiarra. Agora quero saber como fazer do jeito certo.

Tenho um botão. Quando clicado, ele deveria dar play na linha do tempo do início ao fim. Se clicado de novo, deveria dar play ao contrário, do fim ao início.

Tentei isso:

```
var x=0;
if (x==0){
    sym.getSymbol("timeline").play('start');
    x=1;
} else {
    sym.getSymbol("timeline").playReverse('finish');
    x=0 ;
}
```

Isso não funciona. Não sei onde errei. Acabei fazendo o seguinte:

Criei duas divs, `Symbol1` e `Symbol2`. Elas ficam uma sobre a outra. Quando a primeira foi clicada, ela deu play na timeline e desapareceu (mostrando a div inferior), de modo que o segundo símbolo fosse clicado, dando play reverse. Após isso o `Symbol1` reapareceria, reiniciando o processo.

Código:

```
// Symbol2:
sym.getSymbol("timeline").play('start');
sym.$("symbol2").hide();

// Symbol1:
sym.getSymbol("timeline").playReverse('finish');
sym.$("symbol2").show();
```

Como fazer isso funcionar? O segundo modo funciona mas é trabalho duplo (fazer isso pra um botão é fácil, quero ver fazer pra vinte, o que viraria 40, já que são dois botões pra cada parte).

[Link para a arte](http://arte.folha.uol.com.br/cotidiano/2015/10/06/agrotoxicos/)

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente, eu não consigo testar este código porque não consigo fazer um jsfiddle que me retorne as imagens que tu estás a usar no teu servidor. No entanto, este script deverá funcionar:

```
Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${Pimentao2}", "click", function(sym, e) {

if ($(this).attr('data-show')) {
    sym.getSymbol("Pimentao2").playReverse('volta');
    $(this).attr('data-show',false)
} else {
    sym.getSymbol("Pimentao2").play('vai');
    $(this).attr('data-show',false);
}
});
```

O que estavas a fazer de mal era que a variavel `x` estava a ser definida sempre que existia um clique, então `x` era *sempre* `== 0`.

Em vez de definires uma variavel, o que tens que fazer é definir um atributo, neste caso `data-show`. Ao clicar no pimentão, ele vê "este elemento tem data-show?" (está a mostrar a data?) - se isto for verdade, então ele faz o `playReverse` e *retira* o atributo do elemento, caso contrário ele faz `play` e adiciona o atributo `data-show` ao elemento.

---

Eu não sei bem como funciona o Adobe Edge Animate, mas, suponho que possas melhorar este `selector` para funcionar para todos os butões para não teres que repetir esta função.

Qualquer coisa como `Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "#Stage_info > div:not(.Stage_info_largura_id)", "click",` - Este `selector` diz "Todas as divs que são filhas do #Stage_info que não sejam a Stage_info_largura"

*Claro que ao usares este selector terás que mudar parte da função acima, para não selecionar o "Pimentão2" por defeito, mas selecionar o item clicado.*